# onKeyEvent() inside accessibilityService is not working as intended

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

I've added an `onKeyEvent()` inside an `AccessibilityService` . I know when an key press happens (in my case a volume button),`onKeyEvent()` is called twice one for ACTION_DOWN and one for ACTION_UP.

When the user provides the Accessibility permission and opens my application , everything works perfectly.

Then the user kills my app and this time when i press the volume button `onKeyEvent()` called 4 times (2 ACTION_DOWN and 2 ACTION_UP).

Then the user opens my app and then kills it from the recent apps.This time
`onKeyEvent()` is called 6 times(3 ACTION_DOWN and 3 ACTION_UP)

This goes on and on

I'm not doing anything in `onAccessibilityEvent()` and `onDestory()`.

On advice of @Mike M , i've changed to onServiceConnected, but i'm still facing the same error

In `onServiceConnected()` i'm doing this:

```
    info.flags=AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REQUEST_FILTER_KEY_EVENTS;

    info.flags=AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REPORT_VIEW_IDS;

    setServiceInfo(info);
```

This is my onKeyEvent()

```
 @Override

  public boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    Log.v("accessibilityservice","inside onKeyEvent")

    int action = event.getAction();

    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();

    if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {

            Log.d("Hello", "KeyUp");

        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {

            Log.d("Hello", "KeyDown");

        }

        return true;

    } else {

        return super.onKeyEvent(event);

    }

}
```

How do i solve this?

Comment: Will that help resolve this error?

Comment: Now that u say it, i think i have configured in both xml as well as onStartCommand()

Comment: I observed this is happening only in rooted devices.It works fine in non rooted devices

Comment: If that happens only in rooted devices, then it's an anomaly, which means you have to handle it the bad one, one of which might be, for example, regarding only the first event in a specified time window (e.g. 200ms) and disregard the other repetitive events.

Comment: Obviously the service is not being killed along with your app.  It may be useful to describe the backstory/underlying reason behind this "problem."  What are you trying to accomplish from a user standpoint and why?  For example, if all you're doing is trying to detect when the user presses the volume up/down, then you don't need an accessibility service.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to detect if the service/app is already registered in `OnServiceConnected` event or some longer lifecycles?

Answer (score 0):

```
Stop the service when your app stops (in onDestroy)
in Kotlin (translate in java with decompiler)
 autoClickService?.let {
            Log.d("DBGAPP", "stop auto click service Ondestroy")
            it.stopSelf()
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                it.disableSelf()
            }`enter code here`
            //autoClickService = null
        }
```